# Double Linked List - Can't write iterator that gives nodes proper index number

Tags: c, list, loops, iteration

I want to implement the Split function to Learn C The Hard Way Double Linked List but to do that, i need every node to have their index number as regular lists, arrays have. When I do the 'Push' function, which adds new node to the end of the list, everything is fine, but when I do "Unshift", which adds node to the top of list I have problem with keeping each node a proper index number starting from 0. I want at the end of the function make an iterator, that goes through each node and give the first 0, second 1 .. etc. What I have made till now, it's that every node index is being changed to 0 without increasing it. Hope you folks will help me out with this.

```
 'list.h'    
 #ifndef lcthw_List_h
 #define lcthw_List_h

#include <stdlib.h>

struct ListNode;

// ListNode contains value, next, and prev struct. Each ListNode is another
// chain in structure, they are linked
typedef struct ListNode {
    struct ListNode *next;
    struct ListNode *prev;
    void *value;
    int track_num;
} ListNode;

// List is an guardian angel of ListNodes, it keeps tracking them by count
// and knows which Node is first and last
typedef struct List {
    int count;
    ListNode *first;
    ListNode *last;
} List;


// Some standard functions for operate lists
List *List_create();
void List_destroy(List *list);
void List_clear(List *list);
void List_clear_destroy(List *list);

// These Macros return count, first and last element of the list
#define List_count(A) ((A)->count)
#define List_first(A) ((A)->first != NULL ? (A)->first->value : NULL)
#define List_last(A) ((A)->last != NULL ? (A)->last->value : NULL)

// List_push adds a new element to the end of the list
void List_push(List *list, void *value);
//List_pop takes the last element of the list and returns it
void *List_pop(List *list);

// Unshift adds element to the top of the list
void List_unshift(List *list, void *value);
// Shift retuns and remove first element from the list
void *List_shift(List *list);

// Removes list
void *List_remove(List *list, ListNode *node);

// This Macro is very useful, It Iterates through elements in the list
#define LIST_FOREACH(L, S, M, V) ListNode *_node = NULL;\
    ListNode *V = NULL;\
    for(V = _node = L->S; _node != NULL; V = _node = _node->M)

#endif


'list.c sample with subject function'
void List_unshift(List *list, void *value)
{
    int i;
    assert(list != NULL);
    assert(list->count >= 0);
    if(list->count > 0) {
       assert(list->first != NULL);
    }

    ListNode *node = calloc(1, sizeof(ListNode));
    check_mem(node);

    node->value = value;

    if(list->first == NULL) {
        list->first = node;
        list->last = node;


    } else {
        node->next = list->first;
        list->first->prev = node;
        list->first = node;


    }

    list->count++;

      LIST_FOREACH(list, first, next, cur) {
           for(i = 0;i < list->count -1;i++) {
               cur->track_num = i;
           }
        }
error:
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"cur" is an invariant inside the for-loop

```
for(i = 0;i < list->count -1;i++) {
  cur->track_num = i;
}
```

and, "for(i = 0;i < list->count -1" is an 'off by one'. Say list->count equals 1, list->count-1 is "0" and "for(i = 0; i < 0;i++)" does nothing

Comment: Yes, you're right. But even if I'm trying to play with this condition in loop, still the final result of this function is wrong. Can you give me some tips that could be helpful in dealing with this problem?